# Add css Class on html element using JavaScript in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm working on a theme in WordPress I want to add a new class to an element without removing existing class in this theme there is a place
   to add javascript code in theme option with my new class this button
   will toggle to a form here is the code that I want to add my new
   class into it.

```
<a href="" target="_self" class="mk-button custom button-5509e751af089 dark-color  flat-dimension large pointed  "><span>ّFORM</span></a>
```

Comment: jQuery is included in Wordpress, so it's just `$('.button-5509e751af089').addClass('someClass')`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is included by default in WordPress, this can be done by:

```
$('.button-5509e751af089').toggleClass('myClass');
```

With regular JavaScript, I would do the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('button-5509e751af089')[0].classList.toggle('myClass');
```

These method will only toggle the class of the first item, unlike the jQuery answer.

More information on classList [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

---

If you would like the value of the class to be from an input, replace `'myClass'` with the following
jQuery:

```
$('input.myInput').val();
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('inputClassHere')[0].value
```

---

EDIT: One can also use `.querySelector(".myClass")` instead of `.getElementsByClassName('myClass')[0]`

Comment: Instead of using `document.getElementsByClassName('class')[0]`, one could simply use `document.querySelector('.class')`.

Comment: @PierreWahlgren Valid point, but while querySelector has a higher support, it is slower. Considering it is only one element, it might not make such a difference.

Comment: Yea, exactly. If it were a large list of elements, I'd also opt for `getElementsByClassName`. In this case, though, I think it's a more elegant solution, to get rid of `[0]`. :- )

Comment: @Mehran could you possibly add a JSFiddle so we could precisely see and debug your problem?

Comment: @Mehran did you war all the code in an window.onload=function(){} ?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on if you want to add this class to all buttons on the page or just one. assuming you want all buttons, you would do the following:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".mk-button");

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    var el = elements[i]
    el.className = el.className + " new-class-here";
}
```